# Dragging tables in phpmyadmin designer view

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am not able to move the tables in designer view phpmyadmin nor see the relationsips between tables. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YNJb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From phpMyAdmin github [issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13018#issuecomment-331883127):

> It turns out to be with Kaspersky Internet Protection. I had to disable it via (Kaspersky Settings > Additional > Network > Traffic Processing > Inject Script) to get the designer page working as intended but doing so also disables a number of browser security components within Kaspersky!

From phpMyAdmin [docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-errors-about-violating-content-security-policy):

> This is usually caused by some software, which wrongly rewrites Content Security Policy headers. Usually this is caused by antivirus proxy or browser addons which are causing such errors.
>
> If you see these errors, try disabling the HTTP proxy in antivirus or disable the Content Security Policy rewriting in it. If that doesn’t help, try disabling browser extensions.